# array walking cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Answer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 52
                    [body] => test
                    [field] => 2
                    [user] => 1
                                    ) ) )
```

I need to get the value of user.

I was using foreach function like this

```
function testAsim(){

        $listoFArray = $this->myArrays->find('all');
        $i = 0;
        foreach($listoFArray as $myanswers){
            foreach($myanswers as $finalanswer){
            echo $finalanswer[$i]['Answer']['user'];
            }
            $i++;
        }

}
```

But this is generating an error. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$arrays = $this->myArrays->find('all');
$users = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array){
    $users[] = $array['Answer']['user'];
}
```

`Set::extract`, as [proposed by José](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494429/array-walking-cakephp/5494496#5494496), is a great Cake way to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Set::extract() :

`$userValues = Set::extract('/Answer/user', $listoFArray);`

This will return an array you can echo or do whatever you like